# (memcached + relational db) vs nosql

Tags: database, memcached, scalability, nosql

Memcached + relational db looks like a good solutions if you don't have to scale in magnitude of twitter or facebook... are there reasons when NoSQL would be preferred even if high scalability is not a requirement..

Comment: Remember to upvote answers that are of help and choose the answer that best answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Re: are there reasons when NoSQL would be preferred even if high scalability is not a requirement

Yes, NoSQL (eg couchdb) entries can have attributes in addition to the value itself.

You can fake it with memcache by serializing the attributes + value into the memcache store.

Answer (score 0):

A possible advantage would be one you don't have in memcached: 'fuzzy' matching on key (key ranges and the like), and more control over your key store in nosql then in memcached itself, which would require a per-key unset/update, compared to a batch retrieve/update in nosql.

As far as I gather general statistics & relations could be harder to retrieve, and depending on the data, saving/updating could be more intensive on systems not requiring high scalability.